Modifying an existing PowerPoint presentation through JavaScript?
I'm looking for ways to modify an existing PowerPoint presentation using JavaScript (in Node) and replace certain placeholders put in the presentation with data fetched from elsewhere. The flow I am looking for is for the user to upload a templated presentation (has placeholder tags wherever required and with appropriate names for each tag) and then return to them a modified version with every placeholder removed and the relevant data added. So the uploaded file would have slides that kinda look like this:

The closest thing I found that fulfills this is docxtemplater, however, the module that achieves the functionality I want is paid and I am looking for something free.
